# React form with 4 drop down boxes. Will I use only 1 component?

Tags: reactjs

This is a report application for our website. I am currently putting 4 select inputs to generate reports. **Do I have to put them in one component**? If into many components, **how do I send one value to the other component**? as the first drop box (Report Attribute) will change the 2nd combo box(Type).

Report Attribute 
 - Alerts 
 - Mileage 
 - Fuel 
 - Maintenance

Type 
 if (attribute = alerts) 
 - Boundery 
 - Speeding 
 - Arrival Notice 
 - Departure Notice 
 if (attribute = Mileage) 
 - Mileage by Update 
 - Mileage Summary 
 - Mileage between Stops 
 - Mileage by Trip 
 if (attribute = Fuel) 
 - Fuel by Update 
 - Fuel Summary 
 - Fuel between Stops 
 - Fuel by Trip 
 if (attribute = Maintenance) 
 - Summmary 
 - by Hours 
 - by Groups

Plate Number 
 - from data

Duration
 - 3 hrs 
 - 12 hrs 
 - 3 days 
 - date Range

Here is my current code:

```js
var ReportAttribute =  React.createClass({

    render: function() {
      return (
        <select id="ReportAttribute" onChange={this.Type}>
          <option value="" disabled> - Attribute - </option>
          <option value="alerts">Alerts</option>
          <option value="mileage">Mileage</option>
          <option value="fiat">Fuel</option>
          <option value="audi">Maintenance</option>
        </select>
      )
    }
  });

  var Type = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <select id="type" onChange={this.handleType}>
          <option value="" disabled> - Type - </option>
          <option value="by_update">Fuel by Update</option>
          <option value="summary">Fuel Summary</option>
          <option value="bet_stops">Fuel between Stops</option>
          <option value="by_trip">Fuel by Trip</option>
        </select>
      )
    }
  });

  var VehicleID = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <select id="vehicleId" onChange={this.handleVehicleId}>
          <option value="" disabled> - Vehicle - </option>
          <option value="GXN_825">GXN 825</option>
          <option value="GXL_216">GXL 216</option>
          <option value="7CE_1501">7CE 1501</option>
          <option value="AAE_3799">AAE 3799</option>
        </select>
      )
    }
  });

  var Duration = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <select id="duration" onChange={this.handleDuration}>
          <option value="last_3h">Last 3 hrs</option>
          <option value="last_6h">Last 6 hrs</option>
          <option value="last_12h">Last 12 hrs</option>
          <option value="last_24h">Last 24 hrs</option>
          <option value="last_3d">Last 3 Days</option>
          <option value="date_range">Date Range</option>
        </select>
      )
    }
  });



  var ReportForm =  React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
          <form>
            <ReportAttribute />
            <Type />
            <VehicleID />
            <Duration />
          </form>
        );

      }

   });

   var VehicleReports = React.createClass({
    
    render: function() {
        return (
          <ReportForm ReportAttribute={ReportAttribute} Type={Type} VehicleID={VehicleID} Duration={Duration} />
        );

      }

   });


  ReactDOM.render(
     /** @jsx React.DOM */  
    <VehicleReports />,
    document.getElementById('div_reports')
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Sibling components shouldn't know about one another. So you'll want to

1. Put `reportAttribute` in the state of the parent component `ReportForm`.
2. Pass a `reportAttributeChangeHandler` method from the `ReportForm` component into the `ReportAttribute` component.
3. Then you can pass `reportAttribute` as a prop into the `Type` component.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) Trying to figure out step 2. Will update you when i get this running.